# Null error when rendering page within a different view but not when accessing directly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, view, partial-views

In a file called AdminController, I have the following Index action method:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View(UserManager.Users);
}
```

This works fine when I access the view directly at http://localhost:PORTNUMBER/Admin, but when I try to render this view within another view, using

`@RenderPage("~/Views/Admin/Index.cshtml")`

I get a null model error. How can this be fixed so that the view shows up here just like it does when directly accessed?

Here is the header of the view I am interested in seeing:

```
@using IdentityDevelopment.Models
@model IEnumerable<AppUser>
@{ ViewBag.Title = "Index"; }
```

And here is the header of the View (also an Index.cshtml file) I want the above view to appear in:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You need to pass the model when you call `RenderPage`.

Comment: Maybe you should use `@Html.Action` instead

Comment: @Hackerman that helped, thanks.

Comment: No problem @ITWorker, I am glad to help :)